# What is the easiest way to see if a process with a given pid exists in Python?

Tags: python, posix

In a POSIX system, I want to see if a given process (PID 4356, for example) is running.  It would be even better if I could get metadata about that process.

Comment: Related question: [How to detect if a process is running using Python on Win and MAC - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135899/how-to-detect-if-a-process-is-running-using-python-on-win-and-mac#comment54164756_8136371)

Answer (score 11):

Instead of os.waitpid, you can also use os.kill with signal 0:

```
>>> os.kill(8861, 0)
>>> os.kill(12765, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
>>>
```

Edit: more expansively:

```
import errno
import os

def pid_exists(pid):
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)
    except OSError, e:
        return e.errno == errno.EPERM
    else:
        return True
```

This works fine on my Linux box. I haven't verified that "signal 0" is actually Posix, but it's always worked on every Unix variant I've tried.

Comment: This approach is completely flawed: In most situations, it lists only processes started by your user. When a nontraditional authorization module comes into play, it won't work at all.

Comment: I don't think it is completely flawed. It tells you whether a process exists or not, which is what was asked for. (errno lets you differentiate between "does not exist" and "you are not allowed".) Non-traditional modules can break anything, of course.

Comment: @liw.fi Only if the process has been started by you in the first place. At least on my system, I get error 10 all the time

Comment: Error 10 seems to be ECHILD. I don't see how kill(2) could give that. Anyway, my pid_exists function above works for all the processes I tried it on, including init.

Comment: Sending signal 0 to a process is documented in http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html.

Comment: Note that `os.kill` will also report thread/LWP IDs as running, which may not be what you want. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1826824/316723

Answer (score 4):

On linux at least the /proc directory has what you are looking for. It's basically system data from the kernel represented as directories and files. All the numeric directories are details of processes. Just use the basic python os functions to get at this data:

```
#ls /proc
1      17    18675  25346  26390  28071  28674  28848  28871  29347  590   851   874  906   9621  9655       devices      iomem     modules ...

#ls /proc/1
auxv  cmdline  cwd  environ  exe  fd  maps  mem  mounts  root  stat  statm  status  task  wchan

#cat /proc/1/cmdline
init [3]
```

Answer (score 3):

In a portable way, by using psutil ( https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil )

```
>>> import psutil, os
>>> psutil.pid_exists(342342)
False
>>> psutil.pid_exists(os.getpid())
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at `/proc/pid`. This exists only of the process is running, and contains lots of information.

Comment: @zgoda Not only on Linux, although it's not in POSIX. afaik, /proc is available on Linux, Solaris, BSD(except Max OS X), AIX and Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

[`os.waitpid()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.waitpid) might be of help:

```
try:
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
except OSError:
    running = False
else:
    running = True
```

Comment: waitpid waits until the process exits. Therefore, the result is always False. Additionally, waitpid can only be called on child processes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this to get information would be:

```
import commands
output = commands.getstatusoutput("ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | grep MYPID")
```

See: http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html

I think:

```
commands.getoutput(...)
```

could be used to get metadata available on the '`ps`' line. Since you're using a POSIX system, I imagine `ps` (or equivalent) would be available (e.g. `prstat` under Solaris).

Comment: Better to use the "subprocess" module (see http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module)

Comment: Agreed - using the more up-to-date module would be preferable.